# Banned from asking questions

Tags: discussion

I am on StackOverflow for around 8 years. I have learned to code from StackExchange sites. My WordPress StackExchange account has is not allowed to ask anymore questions from a year. I was able to ask a question few days ago but after that again my questions are again blocked. I read [this](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/) and probably thought the rule would be eased but it hasn't.

Answer (score 7):

38 of your 75 questions have been deleted, either by the garbage collector or by yourself. That's a lot.

You can see the recently deleted questions and edit them so that they meet our [quality criteria](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/asking). After you have done that, flag those questions, and a moderator will review and undelete them.

Or write good answers.

Once you have "proven" to the system that you are able and willing to follow the quality rules of our site, the ban will be lifted automatically.

See also [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

Comment: I can't access any of my deleted questions. Its a shame that the community does not help people who are learning.

Answer (score 5):

That post doesn't mean rules are being relaxed but that people shouldn't be super sarcastic or mean in enforcing them, rules are there for a reason. The post is about people and their conduct.

It's when somebody just closes as off topic and leaves a snarky comment is the issue. Fundamentally some questions are good, but they don't fit into our format.

Additionally, it's not always clear to a new user what a well written question looks like. They might have a great question but because they didn't put it across and made assumptions about what people know, it gets lost in translation or misinterpreted.

But all in all, the question banning etc is all automated, even us moderators have little insight as to the exact cues it looks for.